# itextsharp on asp.net page: css don't go

Tags: asp.net, itext

I'm trying to export an asp.net panel in pdf with itextsharp. but css don't go and I don't know why.

This is the aspx:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlPerson" runat="server">
        <table border="1" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; width: 200px">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="background-color: #18B5F0; height: 18px; color: White; border: 1px solid white">
                    <b>Personal Details</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Name:</b></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Age:</b></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblAge" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>City:</b></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblCity" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Country:</b></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" Text="Export" OnClick="btnExport_Click" />
```

And this is code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //Populate DataTable
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Name");
            dt.Columns.Add("Age");
            dt.Columns.Add("City");
            dt.Columns.Add("Country");
            dt.Rows.Add();
            dt.Rows[0]["Name"] = "Mudassar Khan";
            dt.Rows[0]["Age"] = "27";
            dt.Rows[0]["City"] = "Mumbai";
            dt.Rows[0]["Country"] = "India";

            //Bind Datatable to Labels
            lblName.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
            lblAge.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Age"].ToString();
            lblCity.Text = dt.Rows[0]["City"].ToString();
            lblCountry.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Country"].ToString();
        }
    }


    protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Panel.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        pnlPerson.RenderControl(hw);
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();

    }
```

Someone can help me please?

Comment: This is because you are using `HTMLWorker`. For iText 5 you should use `XMLWorker` and for iText 7 you should use pdfHtml.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.